# Which Excel formula is more elegant for this data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I'll try to be succinct and I'll provide an image for clarity at the bottom.

The problem:
I have a large set of data consisting of City resources (publicly available) which includes the information at the parcel level regarding each parcels General Plan designation, Zoning district, and the dwelling units per acre allowed at both the General Plan and Zoning levels. I am trying to parse the data into conforming and non-conforming values. The picture that follows is a table based on the conforming values and their associated dwelling units per acre.

What I would like to do:
If the General Plan designation and Zoning district match the table, give it a value of zero, if it doesn't match the table then give it the value of the General Plan Maximum Dwelling Units per Acre * the number of acres (which I would repeat for zoning).

What formulas I have used:
=VLOOKUP(D2,Info!$H$3:$J$35,3,FALSE)
This was used to find the value of the General Plan (D2) against the Table (H3-J35) and output the third row (dwelling units per acre) that exactly matched the General Plan (D2). The table linked has changed since then so they don't match entirely 1:1

Limitations:
VLOOKUP doesn't work well with multiples of the same General Plan designation with unique Zoning districts that each have unique dwelling unit per acre numbers. This results in needing multiple columns of redundancy to achieve something I feel might be more elegant.

[image: The Data]

Comment: please [edit] your question to provide more clarity. Where are you writing this formula? That is, where is the output field? Please include column and row identifiers in your screenshot to aid in understanding your sample data setup.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a helper column that will combines your multiple columns to one column with each item in that column begin unique. Then your VLOOKUP will reference that cell

Comment: To avoid helper columns, you can use something like `(myGP=GP)*(myZ=Z)` to generate an array which will return a match for the matching row in your table. Then use `INDEX(table,MATCH(...),column)` to return the desired values

Comment: Not very clearly about the result you need, please provide more information.